# Plane is not solid in cell fracture, but explodes

Tags: mesh, physics

I'm trying to make fractured glass from a bullet from the Blender Guru tutorial [Make glass smash animation](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-glass-smash-animation/) and I'm not sure why my plane explodes when it should be solid.  I tried messing with the margin in mesh data in cell fracture, but no matter how far apart or close together, the shards explode.

As you can see from the plane on the left, it's totally unstable.

[image]

Here's the .blend

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. Had to reduce the source limit.